# Showing Menu in one of the fragments of View Pager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having Viewpager with 3 fragments. I want to show menu in only one of the fragments.

1st, I don't know why `toolbar.inflateMenu` doesn't work.

2nd, the menu works, if I have onPrepareOptionsMenu method and do

`getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_user, menu);` but the menu is displayed in all the fragments.

So, according to other questions in stack overflow, I implemented the below code, but it doesn't show the menu, it enters the method but menu is not shown.

```
override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_user, menu);
    info("Menu=>${tabs_viewpager.currentItem}")
    val menuItem = menu?.findItem(R.id.addUserMenu)
    menuItem?.setVisible(tabs_viewpager.currentItem == 1)
    return true
}
```

The control comes to this method and shows currentItem. But it doesn't display the menu. Menu is there with id. Can someone direct me what can I correct to get this work?

Answer (score 1):

try calling setHasOptionsMenu(true); in oncreate() of the fragments where you want the menu to show (you can set it to false in the fragments where you do not want the menu to show).

also include:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    // your code
}
```

in the fragments where you want to set/change the menu. this is called everytime before the menu is shown.

you can also call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` or `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` (if you're using the support library) to force `onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)` to be called.

you may want to check out  [this menus tutorial](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-menus-in-your-apps-a-tutorial.html)

good luck

clive